# Experiencing strange behaviour when trying to make my boss gameObject flicker before a charge?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to code a behaviour for my boss where it charges at the player but before charging it is supposed to flicker a bit to show intent of charge. Below is how I am achieving this in `Update()`:

```
if (chargeTimer <= 0)
            {
                if (!returnToStart)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(TankSpriteFlicker());
                    if (chargeNow)
                    {
                        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, chargeTarget, Time.deltaTime * chargeSpeed);
                        // Target reached?  If so, start moving back to the original position
                        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, chargeTarget) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
                        {
                            returnToStart = true;
                            this.chargeTimer = this.chargeRate;

                        }
                        chargeNow = false;
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, tankStartPosition, Time.deltaTime * returnSpeed);

                    // Original position reached?  If so, start moving to the target
                    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, tankStartPosition) <= Mathf.Epsilon)
                    {
                        returnToStart = false;
                        this.chargeTimer = this.chargeRate;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.chargeTimer -= Time.time;
            }


IEnumerator TankSpriteFlicker()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            tankSprite.color = Color.red;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
            tankSprite.color = startColor;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
        chargeNow = true;
    }
```

`chargeTarget` is a fixed value of `chargeTarget = new Vector3(-2.5f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

The problem with this is that it charges, but stops midway and then charges again.

Also as time passes by the flickering becomes very random and it starts flickering during and after a charge..

Here is the problem in action:

https://gfycat.com/latefrigidbullmastiff-rivalsofaether

I can't explain any of this behaviour and cant fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use Time.deltaTime to decrease the waitTime. Otherwise the chargeTimer gets reduced by the amount of total time passed in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is not how coroutines work

Lets look at just these lines:

```
StartCoroutine(TankSpriteFlicker());
if (chargeNow) { ... }
```

You start a coroutine, that's fine, but your *next instruction* asks if the coroutine has been completed (as `chargeNow` is not set to true until the last line of the coroutine). This cannot and will not ever be true at this point in the execution because coroutines are fundamentally "go do this stuff later" and later is not now.

You need to move these additional pieces of logic (the stuff that happens "after" the coroutine) to the end of the coroutine.